# assign DB name to some varibale while executing script using CMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have more than 1 sql scripts. I want to execute them using only 1 SQLCMD line instead of writing separate SQLCMD line for each script. There's a way where i can create a new .sql file and by using :r . I just need to assign a sql script name in-front :r but the scripts which i am going to execute refers to more than one DB. I prepared the following script but its not working as expected:

Script-1

```
INSERT INTO [$(dbuser1)].[dbo].[A](Name)
VALUES('Tod')

INSERT INTO [$(dbuser2)].[dbo].[B]( Name )
VALUES ('John')
```

Script-2

```
INSERT INTO [$(dbuser1)].[dbo].[A]( Email )
VALUES('tod@gmail.com')

INSERT INTO [$(dbuser2)].[dbo].[B]( Email )
VALUES ('john@gmail.com')
```

Script-3

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET NOEXEC OFF

-- Quit when error.
:On Error Exit

-- SQLCMD Variables
:setvar dbname1                 TestDatabase1
:setvar dbname2                 TestDatabase2

:r Script-1.SQL
:r Script-2.SQL
```

and CMD Line

```
sqlcmd -S <Serevrname> -i <Script-3 path>
```

is it a correct way by assigning DB name to variable?

Comment: String literal values are enclosed in double quotes in SQLCMD `:setvar VariableName "StringLiteral"`. You can use them in referenced scripts using the `$(VariableName)` notation. If it is a DBName, you may want to enclose it in square brackets: `[$(VariableName)]`

Comment: Still not working..

Comment: Then define 'not working'

Comment: Could u plz check the above code?
I am doing the same thing..
But its still not working

Comment: Script 1 and script 2 use variables `dbuser1` and `dbuser2`.  Script 3 uses variables `dbname1` and `dbname2`.

Comment: ohh.. that didnt even come to my mind.. 
tysm @BaconBits :)

Comment: So you most probably got an error stating that $(dbuser1) database does not exist. Next time try to share more info and also provide a full example which reproduces your problem. Marked the question for closing as off-topic/typographical error. I'd suggest to read [ask] in [help].

Comment: yeah.. will keep in mind..thx :)